# Missing angular scope when debugging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I have controller in which i have such broadcast:

```
$scope.seachColumn= function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('seachColumn', true);
}
```

Other controller which listens for the broadcast:

```
$scope.$on('seachColumn', function (event) {
    //console.log($scope);
    console.log('vuala');
});
```

I comment line `console.log($scope)`, then using Chrome explorer I create beakpoint on line `console.log('vuala')`. When Chrome stops on this line and in the console I try to execute command `console.log($scope)` i am getting an error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`

But if I uncomment line `console.log($scope)`, then this line prints `$scope` without error.

Why this is happening?

Comment: can you do a plunkr or something

Comment: this should not happen, could you please add your whole controller code?

Comment: have you added $scope.something i think

Comment: May be debugging mood not pausing the full environment. That's why loosing $scope.

Comment: Chrome Debugger likes to do that for some reason - You can only evaluate things defined in the current frame... Try clicking up a level or two in the call stack

Comment: Tried to test on Firefox explorer and got the `$scope` using commented line in code. So far only on Chrome noticed such behavior.

Comment: `$scope` belongs to the controller's local scope. When you attempt to access `$scope` inside the callback, it will not be availble unless it has been explicitly defined inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity (may not be a solution but might be interesting), what happens if you bind that function (that contains the log call) to the scope that contains $scope?

```
$scope.$on('seachColumn', function (event) {
    //console.log($scope);
    console.log('vuala');
}.bind ( this )); // or whatever context makes sense.
```

Naively, the undefined either means $scope doesn't exist yet (which seems unlikely since the other function that calls the function-as-argument succeeds), or the function exists in another context and the log call can't see it (since it is in that function-as-argument).